# Biggest of 3 numbers code confused me

Tags: c, algorithm, if-statement, numbers

I wrote a piece of code which attempts to tell which of three user-inputted numbers is the greatest. However, I am unable to understand why my code breaks for the input `3, 1, 2` and works for the input `55, 54, 56`.

My code:

```
main()
{
    int a,b,c;
    printf("enter three numbers");
    scanf("%d %d %d",&a,&b,&c);
    if(a>b && a>c)
        printf("%d is greatest",a);
    if(b>a && b>c)
        printf("%d is greatest",b);
    else printf("%d is greatest",c);
    getch();
}
```

What am I doing that causes this error, and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: Try looking into test-first development...

Comment: @gt You mean "format-first" development?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing "else if", that's for sure.

```
main()
{
    int a,b,c;
    printf("enter three numbers: ");
    scanf("%d %d %d",&a,&b,&c);

    if(a>b && a>c)
        printf("%d is greatest",a);
    else if(b>a && b>c)
        printf("%d is greatest",b);
    else 
        printf("%d is greatest",c);
}
```

Comment: Also, he's missing the case where two or more are equal.  Your code will give the wrong answer when given the numbers 5, 5, 3.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an `else` before the line `if(b>a && b>c)`.

i.e.

```
if(b>a && b>c)
```

should be

```
else if(b>a && b>c)
```

Answer (score 1):

What people say here are true, but for best practice I would reduce the checks in the ifs:

```
main()
{
    int a,b,c;
    printf("enter three numbers: ");
    scanf("%d %d %d",&a,&b,&c);

    if(a>=b) //it's not b.
    {
        if(a>=c)
        {
            printf("%d is greatest",a);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%d is greatest",c);
        }
    }
    else // here you know that b > a, then it's not a.
    {
        if(b>=c)
        {
            printf("%d is greatest",b);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%d is greatest",c);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Although *my* "best practice" dictates that I use `{}` for conditions ;-)

Comment: best practice here would be to use a `MAX` macro, and avoid giant, cluttery conditionals on a trivial statement.

Comment: Dave, haha, indeed. I miss the obvious sometimes.

Comment: I actually don't believe that macros for functions are best practice. inline function and normal optimizer will give the same performance.

Answer (score 1):

try this

**condition? exp1: exp2;**

evaluates to

**if *condition* is true then return *exp1* else return *exp2***

```
int main(){

    int a,b,c;
    printf("enter three numbers");
    scanf("%d %d %d",&a,&b,&c);

    int d = (a >= b)? a: b;
    d = (d >= c)? d: c;

    printf("%d is greatest", d);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second if statement should be else if

Answer (score 0):

Just add a simple else if statement to your code and it should work fine as in :

main()
{

```
    int a,b,c;

    printf("enter three numbers");

    scanf("%d %d %d",&a,&b,&c);

    if(a>b && a>c)

    printf("%d is greatest\n",a);

    else if(b>a && b>c)

    printf("%d is greatest\n",b);

    else printf("%d is greatest\n",c);

    //getch();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try this. Its neater. The problem with your code was that you were missing an else which could have been put along with if.

```
main() {

    int a,b,c;

    printf("enter three numbers");

    scanf("%d %d %d",&a,&b,&c);

    if(a>b && a>c)

       printf("%d is greatest\n",a);

    else if(b>c)

      printf("%d is greatest\n",b);

    else printf("%d is greatest\n",c);

    //getch();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#define MAX(a,b) (((a)>=(b))?(a):(b))
#define MAX3(a,b,c) MAX(MAX(a,b),c)
```